# Use DHCP for WiFi for all TCP/IP settings except default gateway

Tags: macos, network, wifi

My Mac is connected via Ethernet to a router (with internet access through corporate VPN) and to home WiFi where all my devices live in.

So I want my Mac to get all TCP/IP settings for home WiFi via DHCP, **but** to not use default gateway for this connection at all.

Is it possible to ignore or override the gateway setting obtained from DHCP? I know I can specify my own DNS servers, but what about the gateway? I cannot find such option in the Network pane. Maybe there is some CLI way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe this method will only work if your router has a gateway IP on your LAN subnet dedicated to the VPN. Can you confirm this is the case?

Comment: If you have access/ability to edit the DHCP *server settings* you can specify any values you want/need. But the trick here is that most home routers don't give you much choice in specifying those kind of settings on a system by system basis. If you can bring up a replacement DHCP server that should be possible to do... theoretically at least.

Comment: @SteveChambers Hmm, but if I change the DHCP server settings (= remove the gateway), it affects all devices in the WiFi network, doesn't it?

Comment: @Scottmeup I am not sure I follow you. The router hides VPN behind NAT. It works — without WiFi connection.

Comment: you have to be able to edit DHCP server settings on a MAC address basis. You won't get that on most home routers. You'll need some custom firmware or run a DHCP server on one of your computers that has more granular control of what clients get what settings. Those are available but not common at all.

Comment: @shau-kote you need an IP address on your LAN to act as the default gateway in order to access other networks, regardless of your setup (assuming no manual routing is implemented). If you want to direct all of your traffic across your VPN, that IP address needs to be associated with the VPN connection. Afaik it should be possible to change the default route from macOS CLI, but you'll need an IP address on your LAN to point it toward.